# Magento bypass Payment Method

Tags: checkout, payment

I have a requirement where customer is not suppose to pay at the time of checkout and the order will be placed bypassing payment step/method. After order placing, customer will receive an email with a URL that will redirect him to payment step or payment page where the final payment will be done and order will be completed.

This is more than just bypassing the payment method.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the method can be you rename Check/Money order payment method's title to some relevent text and still have Payment method block along with relevent description like the one you mentioned in your question. After that you can ask the user to proceed, and on order email you can keep the link to "your payment gateway" link from where user can pay for their order.

After you receive order payment from other gateway you can then change the order status from backend.

In this way, you do not have to work much or remove the payment block altogether which can be quite a hassle.

Comment: I agree for keeping Check/Money order as payment method. But what if the payment method is Credit Card / Paypal / Authorize.net ?

Comment: I mean just enable the "check/money" order in Magento with relevent title, the customer/user will not know if checkmo is used internally, that if for webshop owner to know and to have some payment method value in database. So basically user will see a payment option with relevent title or description, but internally you will know it is the checkmo method, just to keep things simple and easy. For customer that is only information and they will do the payment from the link in the email! Did you get my point.

Comment: Pls refer this one:

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/magento-place-order-on-behalf-of-customer?noredirect=1#comment24575_16354

Answer (score 0):

I've done something a little similar, actually. We're restricted to a certain payment processor that has to be done after the fact - it's a long story, but that's the end result.

So, what I did was to make a new payment method (search google, a minimal one is actually pretty quick to make), and it does nothing really - no online payments, etc, it's just like the "check_mo" method that comes with Magento, I just did a new one so we could still use the Check/Money Order method later if we wanted.

Then, on the success.phtml template (this is the page that is shown at the end of the order, telling the customer the order number) I have a `<div>` with the z-index set such that it covers the page entirely, and has an iframe to the payment processor, so it's at least somewhat painless to use. Since it's on the success page, I can pass along the order number so later on we can correlate the two things, and confirm that it's paid.

In your case, you could have it just be a link on the success page, or as you said, just put it in an email, etc.

In our case, the customer does still have to click on our payment method, but there's no information they enter in for it, or anything like that. That might be a deal breaker for you, but for us it was a nice compromise, since we still want to offer one or two other methods anyway. Sounds like something very similar might fit your case.